# How do I specify a ruleset from MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild, static-code-analysis

After upgrading to VS 2010 MSBUILD /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true does not work as expected

```
msbuild solution.sln /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true
```

To get faster builds we removed the CODE_ANALYSIS constant for the DEBUG build. But that means thet when running the above msbuild command, it defauls to all rules, instead of using the ruleset we specified in on the "Code Analysis" tab on the project property page.

So now I need to build in release mode to run code analasis (which has the CODE_ANALYSIS constant defined):

```
msbuild solution.sln /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:Configuration=release
```

This however means we get a release build on our dev machines. And this has some side effects in our setup.

Question: How do I specify the rulset from a command line. I was hoping something like:

```
msbuild solution.sln /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:foobar=rules.ruleset
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll have to use the `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` property.

```
msbuild solution.sln /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true;CodeAnalysisRuleSet=GlobalizationRules.ruleset
```

Here is the predefined ruleset list :

- `AllRules.ruleset`
- `BasicCorrectnessRules.ruleset`
- `BasicDesignGuidelineRules.ruleset`
- `ExtendedCorrectnessRules.ruleset`
- `ExtendedDesignGuidelineRules.ruleset`
- `GlobalizationRules.ruleset`
- `MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset`
- `SecurityRules.ruleset`

Comment: The ruleset can also be a link to a file. For example:  `/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true;CodeAnalysisRuleSet="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\ExtendedDesignGuidelineRules.ruleset"`.