# Msbuild warning does not break the build

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, vnext

After execute MSbuild task (under TFS2017) with the following parameters:

```
/m /property:StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings=false /property:StyleCopEnabled=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
```

the compilation succeed. The warning is shown under Summary / build but my expectation is that the compilation would have to finish with error.

The warning is:

> Warning : CA1822 : Microsoft.Performance : The 'this' parameter (or 'Me' in Visual Basic) of ...

Are the MsBuild parameters set incorrectly?

Comment: You want to treat warnings as errors? The parameter you've provided looks like it does the opposite. Maybe try `/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors = true`

Comment: Thanks, I've added that parameter but MSBuild task continues avoiding it, and compiles with no error.

Answer (score 0):

By default all rules for code analysis - warnings. You have to set for critical rules an error property:

1. Select code analysis:

[image]

2. Update the rule properties:

[image]

3. That`ll generate a new ruleset file to your project

[image]

4. You get a failed build

[image]

Also you may create any custom ruleset and use it for your builds: [How do I specify a ruleset from MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178537/how-do-i-specify-a-ruleset-from-msbuild)